# Javascript inline style 'webkitTransform' with safari

Tags: javascript

when i use inline **JavaScript** to insert style.

eg. `document.querSelector('.test').style.color = 'red';`

when i did for transform down below;

```
webkitTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
MozTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
msTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
OTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
```

output inline css: (why webkite-transform is missing the '-'?)

```
webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
min-width: inherit;
```

any reason why this is happening?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: `-` appears be used to capitalize the following letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit need to be upcase :)

**W**ebkitTransform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'